# Duplicate UPDATE MySQL in 2 or more connections

Tags: mysql

I have a high traffic app which sometimes caused a problem while updating a record. For example, there are 5 balls on sale. Then, 2 users make the same connection on the same time to buy that 5 balls. Then, we are going to use this query

`UPDATE table SET balls=balls-5 WHERE marketId=3212`

The problem, that balls is updated to -5 (negative 5). This happen occasionally but I just want to know how to prevent this one. The problem only happened when the update updated on the same timestamp. There is no time diff.

How to handle MySQL UPDATE properly in multiple connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a prerequisite for doing this update is that the `balls` value *cannot* end up being negative, you could just add a check for that to the update statement:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET balls = balls-5
WHERE balls >= 5 AND marketId = 3212;
```

Then, if two threads come in at the same time, only one of them should get a lock on the `marketId = 3212` record to update it.  In the scenario you described in your question, the first thread should succeed, while the second should fail to update.

Comment: On the top of code before UPDATE method, I am doing SELECT balls FROM table WHERE balls >= 5, when balls is not enough it will cancel the process.

Comment: @StuartWilliam ... but that's not enough, because if the two threads both simultaneously select and get a positive result, they will then proceed to attempt doing the update.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how it works now. So, the conclusion is UPDATE or DELETE is locking a row and SELECT does not lock it? That is why, when user get positive, they both will update the row

Comment: More or less, yes, what you stated is correct.  You may the MySQL [documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for more information.